# Use expired build on TestFlight

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store-connect, testflight

Due to the recent changes in the user interface I had no idea how to add a new tester to a existing build. I accidently clicked on 'Expire Build' thinking it to be similar to the previous 'Stop Testing' functionality. However that build got expired and now it does not appear in the TestFlight section. It does show up in the 'Activity'. I want to know if there is a way to use that same build again without having to reupload the build ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can re-add the same build for Testing from iTunesConnect, it will appear in TestFlight.

Comment: @iphonic how can I re-add? Can't find a way

Comment: Goto TestFlight Tab -> External Testers -> Click on (+) you should get previously added builds if not released..

Comment: @iphonic - Doesn't work.

Comment: Even I'm confused how to use it. I have uploaded latest Build using Application loader then it's appear in Activity tab and build tab from iTunes Connect user with "Processing" mode but once processing done it's disappear from build tab from iTunes Connect user but able to see in Activity tab. Now I want to start testing with latest uploaded build but how to do it,  please assist me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 46):

There is one way you can use a build that is expired. Here are the steps:

1. Open Xcode > Window > Organizer.
2. Find the build you want to use from the archives list.
3. Right click the build and select show in finder. Right click the file and select show package contents. double tap on info.plist and expand ApplicationProperties. Update CFBundle version to a greater build number.
4. Go to Products >Application > and right click on the file, then show package contents.
5. Double tap on the info.plist find Bundle version and update the the value to a greater version (same as step 3).
6. Go back to Organizer and upload the build, it will upload and process with the new build number.

Comment: worked great even with a very old build which was previously built with a certificate that has already expired (probably because Apply resigns on upload). Thanks!

Comment: Didn't work for me. I went through the steps above and updated the bundle to a higher build number and saved the plist. When I tried to resubmit, Xcode changed the CFBundle version number back to the original value and told me I needed to use a higher number.

Comment: Only works if the expired build was built on your system. Not if someone else uploaded that build.

Comment: This isn't working anymore with Xcode 13.1

Comment: Worked in Xcode 13.2.1
You can omit steps 4 & 5 by just uploading the version you selected in step 2

Comment: This one worked for me, even without doing steps 4 and 5. The only thing that is not mentioned is that I had to close and open XCode Organizer again after doing the steps.

Answer (score 19):

You just can't. Expired builds can't be used again in TestFlight. They do show up in the Activity section because it's the "history" of your builds, App Store versions and reviews.

Comment: given @reycv9 's answer, can we conclude this answer is incorrect?

Comment: @Paul reycv9's answer relies on having a local history of Archives, which is a pretty bis assumption. This answer is correct.

Comment: @Paul, original question was "without having to reupload the build". reycv9's answer is how to reupload the build.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely will need to re-upload but it can be done very quick and easily

This worked for me:

1. Go to Organizer (Xcode > Window > Organizer)
2. Select the build that expired and you want to re-upload
3. Click "Distribute app" the app build will increase automatically leaving the version as it was